# ModuleNotFoundError installing yellowbrick in Python

Tags: python, k-means, yellowbrick

I am having trouble installing yellowbrick.

I am using Anaconda, hence I took advantage of using the "conda install".

```
# set number of clusters
kclusters = 5

pittsburgh_grouped_clustering = pittsburgh_grouped.drop('Neighborhood', 1)

X = pittsburgh_grouped.drop('Neighborhood', 1)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
!conda install -c districtdatalabs yellowbrick
from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer

# instantiate the model and visualizer
model = KMeans()
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(1,10))

visualizer.fit(X) # fit data to visualizer
visualizer.poof() # draw/show/poof the data
```

I expect the package to be installed. The error message I am receiving is:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yellowbrick'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried installing it.  See https://anaconda.org/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First install `yellowbrick` outside of your code and verify that it actually installed. You can do this through the terminal doing exactly what you say. You may need to upgrade/downgrade your libraries which may not be happening when you install in your script.

Then try and run your script without the `!conda install -c districtdatalabs yellowbrick` because once its installed you don't have to install it again.

Comment: For some reason the "!conda install" was not working even though I was using a Jupyter notebook in Anaconda. I used "!pip install yellowbrick", and it was successfully installed/imported. Thank you for your response! :)

Answer (score 4):

Steps to follow:

1. Open Anaconda Navigator
2. Environments
3. Open Terminal
4. Copy-paste "pip install yellowbrick"

Answer (score 0):

**My experienced the same thing but I tried and it worked by using the following steps :**

1. Open search on your windows
2. Look for anaconda prompt, and click
3. `conda install -c districtdatalabs yellowbrick` (use the following script to install the yellowbrick module)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJbTL.png)

**Where do I get the script from? Here I attach the link:** https://anaconda.org/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).